# Rcpp Loop and Subset Numeric Matrix

Tags: r, rcpp

Is it possible to loop through a matrix and do some analysis of some subset?

In R:

```
for(i in 10:nrow(mat)){
   hist = mat[(i-5):(i),]
   // Do something
}
```

In the above R example, I am looping through the `mat` matrix from 10th row to its last row. On each iteration I subset the most recent 5 obseravations and do something.

Is this possible in Rcpp? The following example is something I tried..

```
  int n_col = sample_data.ncol();
  int n_row= sample_data.nrow();
  int max_lb = 10;
  for( int i=(max_lb+1); i<n_row; i++) {

    SubMatrix<REALSXP> res = sample_data(Range(i-max_lb,i),Range(0,n_col));
    //NumericMatrix hist = res;  //If this is uncommented, it fails when I run it...it pretty much just freezes after some iteration...
    Rcpp::Rcout << "-----------------------------" <<std::endl;
    Rcpp::Rcout << i << "\n" <<std::endl;
    Rcpp::Rcout << res .nrow() <<std::endl; // Dimensions do not match what I have
    Rcpp::Rcout << res .ncol() <<std::endl;
  }
```

In the line `//NumericMatrix hist = res;`, i try to convert it back to type NumericMatrix but it fails.

Comment: Please go to the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) and look at the subset example to answer this question.  In short: _sure!_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to use `SubMat<>` here, the result of the subset operation will convert to `NumericMatrix` directly:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void submat(Rcpp::NumericMatrix x, int max_lb = 10) {
    int n_col = x.ncol();
    int n_row = x.nrow();

    for (int i = max_lb + 1; i < n_row; i++) {
        Rcpp::NumericMatrix res =
            x(Rcpp::Range(i - max_lb, i), Rcpp::Range(0, n_col - 1));

        std::printf(
            "i = %d: [%d x %d]\n",
            i, res.nrow(), res.ncol()
        );
    }
}
```

---

```
submat(matrix(1:40, 20))
# i = 11: [11 x 2]
# i = 12: [11 x 2]
# i = 13: [11 x 2]
# i = 14: [11 x 2]
# i = 15: [11 x 2]
# i = 16: [11 x 2]
# i = 17: [11 x 2]
# i = 18: [11 x 2]
# i = 19: [11 x 2]
```

---

As for why

> it pretty much just freezes after some iteration

was happening, you have an out of bounds access here

```
sample_data(Range(i-max_lb,i),Range(0,n_col));
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which is undefined behavior. And you might say, "yes but it was the *next* line that caused my program to freeze", but that's not really true. You did something illegal in the previous line and for whatever reason the commented-out line is where you "paid for it".